# ORM LITE problemas em salvar colunas bytes

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

Meu app o usuário pode usar a câmera para tirar foto e preciso salvar ela no banco de dados. 
Para salvar no banco de dados eu converto a imagem em um array de bytes, contudo percebi um problema nesse processo quando a resolução da câmera está alta (4:3 16 MB) não funciona e quando eu deixa menor como 16:9 (6 MB) funciona.
Estou usando o ORMLite para salvar e ele não retornar nenhuma exceção de erro quando a câmera está em alta resolução, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

```
        Bitmap photo = null;
        File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
        this.getActivity().getContentResolver(),Uri.fromFile(file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        bytesImage = stream.toByteArray();

        CheckListPendente CheckListPendente2 = new CheckListPendente();
        CheckListPendente2.setId(checkListPendenteId);
        CheckListResposta resposta = new CheckListResposta();
        if (bytesImage != null) {
            resposta.setImageBytes(bytesImage);
        }
        checkListDao = CheckListRespostaDao(helper.getConnectionSource());
                    checkListDao.create(resposta);
```

Comment: Altere a linha para photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream); e funcionou, sabem o motivo?

Comment: O terceiro parâmetro que você passou é referente a qualidade de compressão. Provavelmente deve estar havendo estouro de memória, você não tem nenhuma stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1):

Bem eu dei uma procurada nesse método

```
Bitmap.CompressFormat
```

e acabei achando alguns artigos sobre ele, o ruim é que a maioria está em inglês (não sei se você consegue ler "de boas", mas vale a pena dar uma olhada e entender)

LINK 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177191/bitmap-compressbitmap-compressformat-png-0-fout-making-image-size-bigger-tha

LINK 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

LINK 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090820/how-to-predict-image-size-in-megabytes-after-jpeg-compression

LINK 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487971/how-to-compress-bitmap-as-jpeg-with-least-quality-loss-on-android

Bem o que posso dizer,

```
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

Essa sua linha está comprimindo a imagem para o formato JPEG, e no seu segundo parâmetro do método:

```
compress(<1 parâmetro>,<2 parâmetro>,<3 parâmetro>)
```

Indica o tipo de compressão sendo 0 **máxima** e 100 **minima / quase nula** (**VER LINK 2**)
talvez no seu código ao passar todas devoluções de valores bata o limite de memoria ou devolva um valor maior que o valor inicial do tamanho da imagem (em MB/KB..etc) (**VER LINK 1 e 3**)

O que eu recomendo fazer é

1 - converter todas as imagens para uma resolução padrão

2 - fazer o tratamento necessário (no seu caso converter a imagem em um array de bytes)

3 - seja feliz

OBS: não entrarei em código pois não manjo tanto de ORMLite, mas acredito que com um pouco de tempo e dedicação você consiga sozinho, vale a pena dar uma olhada no **link 2** pois lá ele faz uma conversão/setamento de resolução.

OBS2: O link 4 mostra como comprimir a imagem na menor forma possível, pensando em código e tamanho de arquivo / variável seriam menores valores (que não estorariam o limite da memoria na aplicação, vale a pena dar uma olhada)